# Gatsby build production type undefined errors

Tags: reactjs, build, material-ui, gatsby

I'm getting an error when trying to build production for gatsby, but on develop my website runs with no problem. I'm using Material UI and it's choking on the areas that I'm using the library. Even when I comment those out I get other type undefined errors on areas like passing a prop from parent to child.

When running gatsby build I get:

> failed Building static HTML for pages - 6.444s
>
> ERROR #95313
>
> Building static HTML failed for path "/404/"
>
> See our docs page for more info on this error:
>   https://gatsby.dev/debug-html
>
> 15 |   },   16 |   activeLink: {
>
> > 17 |     color: `${theme.link.active} !important`,
> >          |                          ^   18 |   },   19 |   linkLogo: {   20 |     height: "100%",
>
> WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined

**This is the part of my code that's running into an error during build. It can't be a misuse because on develop it's working.**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
appBar: {
 backgroundColor: "transparent",
 position: "relative",
 boxShadow: "none",
 marginBottom: props => props.data.headerMb,
},
activeLink: {
 color: `${theme.link.active} !important`,
},
}))
```

Even when I comment that part out I get simple type undefined errors when passing a prop to a child component only during `gatsby build`. Honestly confused why there are so many type errors as I comment each one out another shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a 404.js page that was using a component that required props that I didn't pass in. Not sure why during build it didn't tell me that but complained about other pages. 
So make sure if any pages are unused to delete them or they include all the props that are required.

Answer (score -1):

It seems `theme.link` doesn't exist and that's why you are getting that error. You may want to use a default value there and do something like:

```
activeLink: {
  color: `${theme.link ? theme.link.active : 'your-default-color'} !important`
}
```

Comment: theme is provided as an optional parameter in makeStyles to use the default theme values. It works in develop but just not during build of production files. https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook

Comment: Did you try this solution? Because as per what you share, the error says `link` doesn't exist on `theme`. If there is one place at least where it fails, build process will fail, despite it works under `develop`. You may not be working on the part of the site where it fails and that's why it works for you on develop.

Comment: I've edited my question to be a bit more clear I hope. I even comment that part out but it still errors out on other type undefined errors for props on places as simple as passing a prop from parent to child.

As for it working on develop it works everywhere. I've been developing this site for a week and no console errors at all. I'm just at the part of building production.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion tho. What I've been doing is commenting each error that it spits out but it's all different undefined type errors during gatsby build. Feel free to check out my repo if you have free time and run on develop. https://github.com/Wayne-CO/Greenstone-Wellness